# Magento 2 - Moving Custom Options under the main image on Product Page

Tags: magento2, layout, custom-options

Greetings Stack community - 
I'd like to move the first custom option group under the main image (see image). Separating the options is probably not that simple, so I think that moving the "Options with add-to-cart button" to its own row before the main description tabs will be the solution (then I could just use CSS to style it after).

[image: Moving a group of custom options under main image]

How would I do this in the **catalog_product_view.xml** file?

```
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_custom_block" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
    <!--<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>-->
    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_config" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/config.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="prev_next_products" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/prev_next.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="prev_next_products" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_addthis_links" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addthis.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\RickSnippet" name="rich_snippet" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/rich_snippet.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block" ifconfig="porto_settings/product/main_custom_block" before="product.info.main" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block.phtml"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block2" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block2.phtml"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product.clearer" after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/clearer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="product_view_main_custom_block2" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="side_popup" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/side_popup.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can move remove components in this xml file , as per you requirement refer here -https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

**case 1:** custom theme add.

Update the file `YOUR-MAGENTO ROOT/app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` as below

File : **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
            <move element="product.info.options" destination="product.info.media"  />
        </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

**Case 2:** Custom Module add.

Update the file `YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyMyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` with below

File : **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>        
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
            <move element="product.info.options" destination="product.info.media"  />
        </referenceBlock>                        
    </body>
</page>
```

Please clear Mageto cache to view the updated layout changes in front end

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work - creates the following error `Element 'move': This element is not expected.`, and shouldn't there be an  after="" or before="" in the move tag?

Comment: Please post your xml code